# css :active stay element visible

Tags: html, css

Trying to display a menu on element click, I do have the menu visible but only as long as mouse click is pressed..

**html:**

```
<i class="fa fa-sort">
    <div class="popupMenu">
      <ul>
        <li">menu item 1</li>
        <li>menu item 2</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</i>
```

**css:**

```
div.popupMenu {
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index: 1000000;
    color:black;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
.fa-sort  {
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 5px;
}
.fa-sort:hover div.popupMenu {
    display:block;
}
```

What I want is to click the element, and menu to stay visible. I tried the `:focus` approach but with no success.. Is there a way to do it without using JavaScript?

Any help is welcome!

Comment: You're going to want to use JavaScript to achieve this. You should simply toggle the class which makes this element visible on click. jQuery has a simple toggle() method that would serve this purpose but its easy enough to do with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: This is not possible without JS.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using JavaScript. First of all, remove CSS for the hover effect, then;

Alter HTML and assign some IDs

```
<i id="menu-toggle" class="fa fa-sort">
    <div id="menu" class="popupMenu">
      <ul>
        <li">menu item 1</li>
        <li>menu item 2</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</i>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('menu-toggle').addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'block';
});

document.getElementById('menu-toggle').addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    document.getElementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
});
```

This is even easier in jQuery.

Comment: The question asks for an onClick event handler not a mouseover/mouseout

Comment: @jeanpier_re I noticed that but then looking at his code, he has the menu being opened with `:hover` and that's why I went with mouseover/out

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the menu without javascript.
Please try this one. You can get an idea.
The whole code is below; You need to click the small red box.

```css
div.popupMenu {
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index: 1000000;
    color:black;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
.fa-sort  {
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 5px;
    display: block;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.hiddencheckbox{display:none}

.hiddencheckbox:checked+label .fa-sort .popupMenu
 {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="hiddencheckbox" id="hiddencheckbox">

<label for="hiddencheckbox">
<i class="fa fa-sort">
    <div class="popupMenu">
      <ul>
        <li>menu item 1</li>
        <li>menu item 2</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</i>
  </label>
```